# How to set log4net context property specific to an ASP.NET request?

Tags: asp.net, properties, log4net, httpcontext

I've been using log4net to log our ASP.NET web site's log messages, and lately I wanted to add information about the page/handler where the error happened. I decided therefore to add the following line to Global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["page"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
}
```

and like wise I added `%property{page}` to my conversion pattern:

```
<conversionPattern value="%newline%date %-5level %property{page} - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
```

This worked fine for single requests. But then I noticed in my logs that the page property may change during an ASP.NET request. I have logging in one ASHX handler, and in the midst of its processing, the page property would change to a different value that points to an ASPX page. I concluded that there is another request coming to ASP.NET and its `BeginRequest` gets executed and the static page property in `log4net.ThreadContext` gets changed to another value.

Now, I would like to maintain the page property per request, so that I can have the path of the executing page logged to the log consistently. I tried to find an answer, but I came out with nothing. What is the recommended way to solve this problem? I'm sure this is very basic functionality of web server event logging.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since ASP.NET [does not guarantee](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) that the entire page request will be processed on the same thread, I prefer getting the answer from HttpContext.Current [as log4net processes](http://www.2geeks1rant.com/2010/11/log4net-contextual-properties-and.html)  the logging event.

The following `GetCurrentPage` class implements what the log4net manual calls an ["Active Property Value"](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html#active) by overriding its `ToString` method:

```
public class GetCurrentPage
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
      if (null != HttpContext.Current)
      {
          return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
      }
      return string.Empty; // or "[No Page]" if you prefer
  }
}
```

Register this class in Global.asax's `Application_Start` in log4net's GlobalContext.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    GlobalContext.Properties["page"] = new GetCurrentPage();
}
```

When log4net writes the `%property{page}` part of the line it will call the `ToString` method of our `GetCurrentPage` class which will lookup the value in the current request.

Comment: This is genius.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Application_PostAcquireRequestState  instead of Application_BeginRequest as outlined in this article?  [How can I include SessionID in log files using log4net in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362468/how-can-i-include-sessionid-in-log-files-using-log4net-in-asp-net)

We have never felt the need to add the page to the logging since we create our logger in each class with the method name:

```
private static new readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and have a conversion pattern like this:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %P{user} %P{addr} [%property{SessionID}] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
```

So we end up seeing the class name in the log output. This also lets you differentiate whether the logging happened in the page class file itself, vs. a base class it inherits from. Your solution would have the advantage of showing the page name even when the code is executing in the base class. I think we will look at adding {page} to our setup.

Comment: Interestingly this works. BeginRequest is executed asynchronously, but Application_PostAcquireRequestState is processed at the start of a page request, after which all other page events are fired synchronously, and another page request must wait until the first one finishes.

Comment: @CraigA I don't think the 'new' operator is needed in your code line 'private static new readonly log4net.ILog'. Can't edit and remove it, since SO says "Edits must be at least 6 characters" :).

Answer (score 1):

Store property value in ASP.NET context `HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("yourProperty", value)`
It will be available from log4net layout:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-context{yourProperty}" />
</layout>
```

Find more detail [here.](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm)